# Screened Porch questions

Tags: framing, roof, porch

I'm building screened porch with 4x4 wall posts (screens in-between)spaced 48". My question is about the roof.

I have a chimney at one end so was planning on trusses instead of a ridge beam: Double 2x8 rafters sandwiched with a 2x8 rafter tie. These would be spaced 48" (matching the wall posts).

The span of the rafter tie is 20 feet. Is that within Connecticut building code? Alternatives?

Comment: building code. Thanks

Comment: What state/country? There are variations. In MN and AK, they're worried about a bit more snow load than in FL, for example, while in FL, there are concerns about hurricanes that aren't present in MN/AK.

Comment: Connecticut, USA